# How to show that two tabs in my Tablayout using kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a `android` app, developed in kotlin.One of my activity have a tabview with viewpager to show the two tabs but here i have only one tabs is showed anther one does not display.when i open my activity only one tab is showed. what i make mistake please guide me.

```
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection) {

        val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, viewPager, it, incoming, appDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider)

        if(adapter.count < 2) {
            if (incoming.equals(OUTGOING)) {
                adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(it!!, appDatabase, OUTGOING, networkDefinitionProvider), "SEND")

            } else if (incoming.equals(INCOMING)) {
                adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(it!!, appDatabase, INCOMING, networkDefinitionProvider), "RECEIVE")

            }
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0)
            viewPager.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
```

**my guess is, only one frament set in getItem() method**

```
inner class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager) {
        private val mFragmentList = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList = ArrayList<String>()


        private val mfragmentAB = appDatabase
        private val mfragmentIT: List<TransactionEntity> = it!!
        private val mfragmentINC : TransactionAdapterDirection = incoming
        private val mfragmentnetwork : NetworkDefinitionProvider = networkDefinitionProvider

       /* override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            return mFragmentList[position]
        }*/

        /*override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
            val fragment1 = ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
            return fragment1
        }*/

        override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
            } else if (position == 1) {
                fragment = SendingFragment(mfragmentIT,mfragmentAB,mfragmentINC,mfragmentnetwork)
            }
            return fragment
        }

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

        /*override fun getItemPosition(`object`: Any): Int {
            return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }*/

        override fun getItemPosition(fragItem: Any): Int {
            var position = 0
            if (fragItem is ReceiveFragment) {
                position = 0
            } else if (fragItem is SendingFragment) {
                position = 1
            }
            return if (position >= 0) position else PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }
    }
```

**MyFull Code:**

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener, KodeinAware {

    //tab
    private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    //private val tabIcons = intArrayOf(R.drawable.receive_tab, R.drawable.send_tab)
    //end
    /*private var tabLayout: TabLayout? = null
    var viewPager: ViewPager? = null
    private var viewPagerAdapter: ViewPagerAdapter? = null*/
    //end
    override val kodein by closestKodein()
    val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)


    private val actionBarDrawerToggle by lazy { ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer_layout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) }

    private val syncProgressProvider: SyncProgressProvider by instance()
    private val networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider by instance()
    private val appDatabase: AppDatabase by instance()

    private val settings: Settings by instance()
    private val currentTokenProvider: CurrentTokenProvider by instance()
    private val currentAddressProvider: CurrentAddressProvider by instance()
    private var lastNightMode: Int? = null
    private var balanceLiveData: LiveData<Balance>? = null
    private var etherLiveData: LiveData<Balance>? = null
    private val onboardingController by lazy { OnboardingController(this, settings) }

    private var lastPastedData: String? = null
    var t1: Int = 0
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (lastNightMode != null && lastNightMode != settings.getNightMode()) {
            val intent = intent
            finish()
            startActivity(intent)
            //recreateWhenPossible()
            return
        }

        lastNightMode = settings.getNightMode()
        setCurrentBalanceObservers()
        val clipboard = getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        if (clipboard.hasPrimaryClip()) {
            val item = clipboard.primaryClip.getItemAt(0).text?.toString()
            val erc681 = item?.let { EthereumURI(it).toERC681() }
            if (erc681?.valid == true && erc681?.address != null && item != lastPastedData && item != currentAddressProvider.value?.hex.let { ERC681(address = it).generateURL() }) {
                Snackbar.make(fab, R.string.paste_from_clipboard, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .addCallback(object : BaseTransientBottomBar.BaseCallback<Snackbar>() {
                            override fun onDismissed(transientBottomBar: Snackbar?, event: Int) {
                                if (event == DISMISS_EVENT_ACTION || event == DISMISS_EVENT_SWIPE) {
                                    lastPastedData = item
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .setAction(R.string.paste_from_clipboard_action, {
                            alert(R.string.copied_string_warning_message, R.string.copied_string_warning_title) {
                                startActivity(Intent(this@MainActivity, CreateTransactionActivity::class.java).apply {
                                    data = Uri.parse(item)
                                })
                            }

                        })
                        .show()
            }
        }
    }

    private fun String.isJSONKey() = try {
        JSONObject(this).let {
            it.has("address") && (it.has("crypto") || it.has("Crypto"))
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        false
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        if (data != null && data.hasExtra("SCAN_RESULT")) {
            val scanResult = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT")

            when {
                scanResult.isEthereumURLString() -> {
                    startActivity(getEthereumViewIntent(scanResult))
                }

                scanResult.length == 64 -> {
                    startActivity(getKeyImportIntent(scanResult, KeyType.ECDSA))
                }

                scanResult.isJSONKey() -> {
                    startActivity(getKeyImportIntent(scanResult, KeyType.JSON))
                }

            /*scanResult.isUnsignedTransactionJSON() || scanResult.isSignedTransactionJSON() || scanResult.isParityUnsignedTransactionJSON() -> {
                startActivity(getOfflineTransactionIntent(scanResult))
            }*/

                scanResult.startsWith("0x") -> {
                    startActivity(getEthereumViewIntent(ERC681(address = scanResult).generateURL()))
                }

                else -> {
                    AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                            .setMessage(R.string.scan_not_interpreted_error_message)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
                            .show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    fun refresh() {
        val incomingSize = transaction_recycler_in.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0
        val outgoingSize = transaction_recycler_out.adapter?.itemCount ?: 0

        val hasTransactions = incomingSize + outgoingSize > 0
        //empty_view_container.setVisibility(!hasTransactions && !onboardingController.isShowing)
        transaction_recycler_out.setVisibility(hasTransactions)
        transaction_recycler_in.setVisibility(hasTransactions)

        //remove the textview based on the condition
        if(hasTransactions.equals(true)){
            empty_view.setVisibility(View.GONE)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //val dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(applicationContext)

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_in_drawer_container)



        onboardingController.install()

        settings.registerListener(this)

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)
        drawer_layout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle)

        receive_button.setOnClickListener {
            onboardingController.dismiss()
            startActivityFromClass(RequestActivity::class)
        }

        send_button.setOnClickListener {
            startActivityFromClass(CreateTransactionActivity::class)
        }

        fab.setOnClickListener {
            startScanActivityForResult(this)
        }
        transaction_recycler_out.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        transaction_recycler_in.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        current_fiat_symbol.setOnClickListener {
            startActivityFromClass(SelectReferenceActivity::class)
        }

        current_token_symbol.setOnClickListener {
            startActivityFromClass(SelectTokenActivity::class)
        }


        syncProgressProvider.observe(this, Observer {
            val progress = it!!

            if (progress.isSyncing) {
                val percent = ((progress.currentBlock.toDouble() / progress.highestBlock) * 100).toInt()
                supportActionBar?.subtitle = "Block ${progress.currentBlock}/${progress.highestBlock} ($percent%)"
            }
        })



        val incomingTransactionsObserver = Observer<List<TransactionEntity>> {
            Log.e("INDIA", "incomingTransactionsObserver : " + it);

            if (it != null) {

                viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
                t1++

                setupViewPager(viewPager!!, it, INCOMING)

                tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

                transaction_recycler_in.adapter = TransactionRecyclerAdapter(it, appDatabase, INCOMING, networkDefinitionProvider)
                transaction_recycler_in.setVisibility(!it.isEmpty())
                refresh()



            }
        }

        val outgoingTransactionsObserver = Observer<List<TransactionEntity>> {
            Log.e("INDIA", "outgoingTransactionsObserver : " + it);

            if (it != null) {
                viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager)
                t1++
                setupViewPager(viewPager!!, it, OUTGOING)

                tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
                tabLayout!!.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

                transaction_recycler_out.adapter = DuplicateTransactionRecyclerAdapter(it, appDatabase, OUTGOING, networkDefinitionProvider)
                refresh()


            }
        }

        var incomingTransactionsForAddress: LiveData<List<TransactionEntity>>? = null
        var outgoingTransactionsForAddress: LiveData<List<TransactionEntity>>? = null

        //fun installTransactionObservers() {
        fun installTransactionObservers() {

            incomingTransactionsForAddress?.removeObserver(incomingTransactionsObserver)
            outgoingTransactionsForAddress?.removeObserver(outgoingTransactionsObserver)

            currentAddressProvider.value?.let { currentAddress ->
                val currentChain = networkDefinitionProvider.getCurrent().chain
                incomingTransactionsForAddress = appDatabase.transactions.getIncomingTransactionsForAddressOnChainOrdered(currentAddress, currentChain)
                outgoingTransactionsForAddress = appDatabase.transactions.getOutgoingTransactionsForAddressOnChainOrdered(currentAddress, currentChain)

                incomingTransactionsForAddress?.observe(this, incomingTransactionsObserver)
                outgoingTransactionsForAddress?.observe(this, outgoingTransactionsObserver)
            }
        }

        networkDefinitionProvider.observe(this, Observer {
            setCurrentBalanceObservers()
            installTransactionObservers()
        })

        currentAddressProvider.observe(this, Observer {
            installTransactionObservers()
        })

        currentAddressProvider.observe(this, Observer { _ ->
            setCurrentBalanceObservers()
        })

        if (intent.action?.equals("org.walleth.action.SCAN") == true) {
            startScanActivityForResult(this)
        }

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            lastPastedData = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_LAST_PASTED_DATA)
        }
        //progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    private val balanceObserver = Observer<Balance> {

        if (it != null) {

            /* val progressBar: ProgressBar = this.progressBar1
             progressBar.visibility = View.GONE*/

            value_view.setValue(it.balance, currentTokenProvider.currentToken)
            supportActionBar?.subtitle = getString(R.string.main_activity_block, it.block)
        } else {
            value_view.setValue(ZERO, currentTokenProvider.currentToken)
            supportActionBar?.subtitle = getString(R.string.main_activity_no_data)
        }
    }

    private val etherObserver = Observer<Balance> {
        if (it != null) {
            send_button.setVisibility(it.balance > ZERO, INVISIBLE)
        } else {
            send_button.visibility = INVISIBLE
        }
    }

    private fun setCurrentBalanceObservers() {
        Log.e("INDIA","currentAddress")
        val currentAddress = currentAddressProvider.value
        Log.e("INDIA","currentAddress" + currentAddress)

        if (currentAddress != null) {
            balanceLiveData?.removeObserver(balanceObserver)
            balanceLiveData = appDatabase.balances.getBalanceLive(currentAddress, currentTokenProvider.currentToken.address, networkDefinitionProvider.getCurrent().chain)
            balanceLiveData?.observe(this, balanceObserver)
            etherLiveData?.removeObserver(etherObserver)
            etherLiveData = appDatabase.balances.getBalanceLive(currentAddress, getEthTokenForChain(networkDefinitionProvider.getCurrent()).address, networkDefinitionProvider.getCurrent().chain)
            etherLiveData?.observe(this, etherObserver)
        }
    }

    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState()
    }

    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_copy -> {
            copyToClipboard(currentAddressProvider.getCurrent(), fab)
            true
        }
    /*R.id.menu_info -> {
        startActivityFromClass(InfoActivity::class.java)
        true
    }*/
        else -> actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }

    override fun onSharedPreferenceChanged(preferences: SharedPreferences?, key: String?) {
        if (Settings::currentFiat.name == key) {
            transaction_recycler_in.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
            transaction_recycler_in.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState!!.putString(KEY_LAST_PASTED_DATA, lastPastedData)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        settings.unregisterListener(this)
        super.onDestroy()
    }

    //tab
    private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection) {


        //val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, viewPager, it, incoming, appDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider)
        if(adapter.count < 2) {
            if (t1 == 1) {
                adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(it!!, appDatabase, INCOMING, networkDefinitionProvider), "SEND")
            } else {
                adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(it!!, appDatabase, OUTGOING, networkDefinitionProvider), "RECEIVE")
            }
            if (t1 == 2) {
                viewPager.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
    }



    //class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager) {
    //class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager, viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection, appDatabase: AppDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider: NetworkDefinitionProvider) : FragmentPagerAdapter(manager)
    class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager)
    {
        private val mFragmentList: ArrayList<Fragment> = ArrayList<Fragment>()
        private val mFragmentTitleList: ArrayList<String>  = ArrayList<String>()

        /*private val mfragmentAB = appDatabase
        private val mfragmentIT: List<TransactionEntity> = it!!
        private val mfragmentINC : TransactionAdapterDirection = incoming
        private val mfragmentnetwork : NetworkDefinitionProvider = networkDefinitionProvider
        private val mfragmentviewpager : ViewPager = viewPager*/

        override fun getCount(): Int {
            return mFragmentList.size
        }

       /* override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment? {
            var fragment: Fragment? = null
            if (position == 0) {
                fragment = SendingFragment(mfragmentIT, mfragmentAB, mfragmentINC, mfragmentnetwork)
            } else if (position == 1) {
                fragment = ReceiveFragment(mfragmentIT, mfragmentAB, mfragmentINC, mfragmentnetwork)
            }
            return fragment
        }*/

        override fun getItem(position: Int) = mFragmentList[position]

        fun addFragment(fragment: Fragment, title: String) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment)
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title)
        }

        override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
            return mFragmentTitleList[position]
        }

        override fun getItemPosition(fragItem: Any): Int {
            var position = 0
            if (fragItem is ReceiveFragment) {
                position = 0
            } else if (fragItem is SendingFragment) {
                position = 1
            }
            return if (position >= 0) position else PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've added to `mFragmentList` both of fragments, not only one? As I see in `setupViewPager` method - you add only one of them

Comment: sorry i could not understand plz explain more little bit

Comment: As I see, in `setupViewPager` method you add either `SendingFragment` or `ReceiveFragment`, not both. So your `mFragmentList` contains only one fragment

Comment: yes right as per your  idea i added two fragments but the problem is both fragments shows same data

Comment: plz check this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52753163/why-my-viewpagers-all-tabs-shows-same-data

Comment: Im `getItem` you create new instance of fragment with equals parameters. Why don't you do `override fun getItem(position: Int) = mFragmentList[position]`?

Comment: this one also return same result both tabs shows me same data

Comment: How exactly you add two fragments to adapter? Show the code

Comment: i update my ful code plz check it

Comment: You are getting list of some data, then you call `setupViewPager` and create 2 fragments with this 1 list - of course their contents are equal

Comment: how to fix this ?? plz help

Comment: You have to get data in `outgoingTransactionsObserver` and `outgoingTransactionsObserver` and after that create 2 fragments with different data and init adapter

Comment: okay will trythis

Comment: when i use this "override fun getItem(position: Int) = mFragmentList[position]" tab data does not update

Comment: Update your code

Comment: i can fix that same data bug with flags.ow the problem is i need to set the "val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)" globally then only it will work.BUT i need to refresh the lablayout if new data is update means so i need to call "val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, viewPager, it, incoming, appDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider)" inside the "setupViewPager()" then only viewpager auto  update works.

Comment: code updated plz check

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(manager: FragmentManager) : FragmentStatePagerAdapter(manager)
{
val incomingData: List<TransactionEntity> = mutableListOf()
val outgoingData: List<TransactionEntity> = mutableListOf()

override fun getCount(): Int = 2

override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return if (position == 0) SendingFragment(outgoingData, mfragmentAB, OUTGOING, mfragmentnetwork)
        else ReceiveFragment(incomingData, mfragmentAB, INCOMING, mfragmentnetwork)
    }

fun updateData(data: List<TransactionEntity>, isIncoming: Boolean) {
    if (isIncoming) {
        incomingData.clear()
        incomingData.addAll(data)
    } else {
        outgoingData.clear()
        outgoingData.addAll(data)
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
...
```

**UPD**

```
class MainActivity {

val incomingData: List<TransactionEntity> = mutableListOf()
val outgoingData: List<TransactionEntity> = mutableListOf()

...
private fun setupViewPager(viewPager: ViewPager, it: List<TransactionEntity>?, incoming: TransactionAdapterDirection) {


val adapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, viewPager, it, incoming, appDatabase, networkDefinitionProvider)
if(incoming == INCOMING) {
    incomingData.clear()
    incomingData.addAll(data)
} else {
    outgoingData.clear()
    outgoingData.addAll(data)
}
adapter.addFragment(ReceiveFragment(incomingData, appDatabase, INCOMING, networkDefinitionProvider), "SEND")
adapter.addFragment(SendingFragment(outgoingData, appDatabase, OUTGOING, networkDefinitionProvider), "RECEIVE")
viewPager.adapter = adapter
}
...
}
```

Comment: When you get data in your observables - instead of calling `setupViewPager`

Comment: try and come back

Comment: above the logic does not work. i think  in my case adapter is replaced by last values so only i get duplicate data

Comment: viewPager.adapter = adapter to replace the old values instands of holding

Comment: So there are many different ways to solve this. I.e. you can move these lists from adapter to activity and every time create new instances of fragments for adapter

Comment: how to do that ?? any idea but i dont know ehy my adapter to replace the values

Comment: I've update answer. Sorry, but I think it's cleat enough. Don't know what else I can say